# Why is \smallskip so big after display math?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

In the below MWE, why is `\smallskip` adding so much extra space after display math? (And how do I fix it?)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This line.

Next line.
\smallskip

Next line after small skip.

\[displaymath\]

Next line.

\[displaymath\]
\smallskip

Next line after small skip.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The big question is where all the space around display math comes from.  If you put display math in the same paragraph as the lines above and below (the way you are supposed to) the spacing is controlled by \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip.  But when it is in a paragraph by itself, that won't help.  So far everything I have tried (like \partopskip) hasn't worked.

Comment: and don't leave a blank line between text and the following display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good LaTeX syntax is *never* to leave one or more blank lines -- which implicitly generate a paragraph break -- immediately *before* a display-math group. If needed, one can start a new paragraph *after* a display-math group.

If you want to avoid generating an excessive amount of vertical whitespace between the end of one displaymath group and the next paragraph, while still using `\smallskip`, be sure not to insert a blank line between the `\smallskip` instruction and the next paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
This line.

Another line.

\smallskip              % no blank line after \smallskip
Line after a smallskip. % no blank line *before* \[...\]
\[\text{displaymath}\]

Line with no smallskip. % no blank line *before* \[...\]
\[\text{displaymath}\]

\smallskip              % no blank line after \smallskip
Line after a smallskip.
\end{document}
```

Comment: So in general, one should avoid inserting a blank line between a skip instruction and the following paragraph?

Comment: @justin -- A full answer would require knowing a lot more about your document setup. In general, though, I'd say you won't go wrong by *not* having (explicit or implicit) paragraph breaks between a vertical skip  and the subsequent text material.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use blank lines before/after display math. Use it this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    This line.

    Next line.
    \smallskip

    Next line after small skip.
%   
    \[displaymath\]
%   
    Next line.
%   
    \[displaymath\]
    \smallskip

    Next line after small skip.
%
    \[displaymath\]
%   
    Next line after small skip.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd say that if a displaymath group represents the end of a train of thought, it's OK to generate a paragraph-type break between that displaymath group and the start of the following material (which will likely be text).